# jQuery use elements inserted from ajax

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jQuery. I've searched and found some results that might work, but they include using `.live()` which, according to the 1.7 docs, is deprecated. I'm trying to work with `.on()`, but I'm not having any luck. I understand I'm probably trying to use an element that isn't in the DOM yet, but I thought that's what `on()` did.

Here's my initial html:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.ajaxSetup ({
            cache: false// Disable caching of AJAX responses
        });

        $("document").ready( function(){
            $("#displayArea").load('2.html', function(){
                $("#myButton").on("click",function(event){
                    alert('i was pressed');
                })
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id = "displayArea">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here's my button html

```
<input type="button" name="myButton" id="myButton" value="press me"/>
```

Not only do I not get an alert, but I get an error

> Object doesn't support this property or method

Ultimately, I need to insert a table with a form to filter the date, but I can't seem to get this simple task working.
Can someone help me out?

--- Edit ---
I changed the script to read the following (after making sure i'm using 1.7). no errors but no alerts.  2.html is simply the input field, no html or js (for now, at some point it will be a table and form).

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $("#displayArea").load('innerElements.cfm');
$("#myButton").on("click","#displayArea", function(){
         alert('i was pressed');
    });
});
```

Comment: Does the error occur on `.load` or when you click on the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using `.load` the callback is fired after the contents are added to the DOM, thus no need for delegation.

```
$(function() {
   $("#displayArea").load('innerElements.cfm', function() {
       $("#myButton").click(function(){
         alert('i was pressed');
       });
   });
});
```

If the event binding occurred BEFORE the content is added to the DOM you would use.

```
$(function() {
   $("#displayArea").load('innerElements.cfm', function() {
       $("#displayArea").on("click", "#myButton", function(){
         alert('i was pressed');
       });
   });
});
```

Comment: brilliant! thanks. I had the IDs backwards.  now do you know how to make two form fields available? I just need to be able to use their the value, not bind an event. <input id = "fromDate"><input id = "toDate"><input type = "button" value = "refresh view"> I'll probably end up moving the form out of the ajax data but would be good to know anyway.

Comment: actually I just tried some actual code and the values of the newly inserted fields were available to jquery without having to add them to the jquery object(correct term?)  $("myContent").on("click","#submit",function(){$("#myContent").load('ajax/myChart.cfm?otc=custom&from='+$("#from").val()+'&to='+$("#to").val());} --- note --- #from and #to are inserted by the same ajax as the button i'm assigning the event to.

Comment: Travis, dunno if it's important but there's an easier way to add those data elements to the page by using a JSON object rather than string concatenation. `$("#myContent").load('url', { from : $("#from").val(), to : $("#to").val() });` Also, if you want to convert an entire form into a string all `form` elements have a `.serialize` which converts it into a string of params, so `$("#myContent").load('url?' + $("#myContent").serialize());` will work as well.

Answer (score 2):

The callback in `load` is executed only after `load` has completed. So in this case you don't need `live`.

```
$("#displayArea").load('2.html', function(){
    $("#myButton").click(function(){
        alert('i was pressed');
    });
});
```

For reference, the syntax for using `on` would be

```
$(document).on("click", "#myButton", function(){ alert('i was pressed'); });
```

Comment: Actually I feel like a bit of a dork now.  I found that despite having just downloaded it earlier this week from the jquery home page I was using 1.6.4, so yeah... on() wasn't working... you're correct though, I just changed the callback to read $("#myButton").click(...) and it worked fine. So how would I change that to make 2 form fields available to refresh the ajax view once i click the button? i.e. load('2.html?from='&("#fromDate").val())

Comment: @Travis I'm not sure I understand your further question correctly, what exactly do you need to do?

Comment: @Nucleon I have never actually used `on` so I'm not sure, but my example is exactly as the official documentation here http://api.jquery.com/live/ so it seems unlikely that it is incorrect. Do you have a reference?

Comment: Fear: From reading the documentation you are indeed correct. I was completely incorrect and have deleted my comment thanks for setting me straight. Apparently I fail at reading the docs... http://api.jquery.com/on/